# How to know what snapd is downloading and when will it finish?

Tags: snap

The snapd is downloading some update by itself (obviously it's very bad, but whatever).

Journalctl just shows that snapd has started.

How to know when how much has left to download?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To see the list of transactions:

```
snap changes
```

To check the progress of a running transaction (number 240 for example):

```
snap watch 240
```

seeing via: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/advanced-snap-usage#1